# Choose combination of arrays that don't intersect such that one of their attributes add up to a range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have arrays 1 through 5, with their "value", an attribute as follows

```
array 1 - 50

array 2 - 50

array 3 - 75

array 4 - 100

array 5 - 125
```

Also, the arrays contain a set of numbers

```
array 1 - {1,2,3,4,5,6}

array 2 - {7,10,12,13,15,16}

array 3 - {8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}

array 4 - {17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,28,29,30}

array 5 - {7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}
```

Now, upon choosing the requirement range, say 100 to 150, the combinations are

1) arrays 1&2 and 4 for a sum of 1

100 - array 1&2 - {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,12,13,15,16}

100 - array 4 - {17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,28,29,30}

2) arrays 1&3 and 5 for a sum of 1.25

125 - array 1&3 - {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}

125 - array 5 - {7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}

3) arrays 1&4 and 2&4 for a sum of 1.5

150 - array 1&4 - {1,2,3,4,5,6,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,28,29,30}

150 - array 2&4 - {7,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,28,29,30}

These 6 arrays with their appended name, value and number set should be the output. Here, the combination of arrays 2&3 adding upto 125 is not a suitable solution due to intersection of numbers between them - {10,12,13,15,16}. How to go about this?

[image]

What have i tried?

I used intersect() in vba is working for checking the intersection between arrays and I can append the suitable arrays. However, I am stuck in coming up with combinations and dynamically changing the arrays to be checked for intersection.

Comment: So, is this php, python or vba?

Comment: Why is this tagged with php, python, mysql and excel-vba? Which programming language are you using, and what is the code you have come up with so far?